# Multiple Login in PHP sessions

Tags: php, html, mysql, session

Suppose I have 2 users A and B trying to login from the same PC into my website.
A is currently logged in. B uses the same PC and opens a new tab and tries to login.(A hasn't  logged out yet)How do I prevent B from login unless A logs out?

I have used PHP sessions which prevents A from logging in again without logging out but it doesn't stop B from logging in.

Comment: You mean, user B opens a new tab on the exact same browser that user A is logged in? That's doesn't seem like a terribly realistic scenario.

Comment: both A and B use the same pc thats what i meant

Comment: If you configured that when your session has something it will redirect to the dashboard or some sort instead of directing to the login page, I think B can't log in unless A's account has been logged out

Comment: They use the same PC but different browsers? Different user profiles? 'Same PC' is a bit vague.

Comment: i want to disable B login unless A logs out

Comment: Keep track of sessions by user, make sure user A session is not expired? Again, can you be more specific about the scenario?

Comment: Or you can add another column in the db that checks whether that account is logged in or not

Comment: I tried using two different accounts but the second login is not restricted and in the same browser too

Comment: check session. if session content any user then anybody can't access login page

Comment: the only scenario it works is when i try to login again from the same id and password

Comment: Can you edit your question and clarify this step by step? You want user B to _not be able to log in at all_ while user A is logged in? Is that it?

Comment: When B tries to log in, check if there's an existing active session and the username is same or different. If they do it in a new private window, it shouldn't impact A at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent B from accessing the login page, then you can try this:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['logged'])){
    if($_SESSION['logged'] == true){
        header('Location:otherPage.php');
        exit;
    } else {
        header('Location:login.php');
        exit;
    }
}
```

To use the above code, you must make the value of `$_SESSION['logged']` to true after a successful login, then make false after logging out, or you can destroy the session

Comment: @Downvoter Can you explain the reason?

Comment: this doesnt work it still allows login and btw you missed a ')' in the if statement

Comment: @ChethanKille Did you put this in the login page?

Comment: And did you add `session_start()` above all the other codes?

Comment: thanks sir I was missing the session_start()

Answer (score 0):

check session variable (which set after successfull login):

```
 if ($_SESSION["username"] == "")
 {
   // allow to login, check login credentials here
  }
  // else ignore login attempt
```

Comment: Where did `$_GET["action"]` came from? And why do you still need it?

Comment: "part of url => login.php?action=login " as i wrote

Comment: What's the purpose? You can just check whether a session variable has something or not

Comment: ok you are right. If we use standalone script to check login, action is not necessary. I will edit answer

Comment: doesnt work this is similar to @CarlJan answer and allows multiple logins

Comment: then paste full login script